# custom add media button wordpress doesn't work with image from url

Tags: php, wordpress

i got a problem with custom add media button wordpress when trying to insert to post. when i tried insert to post from url the image wasn't show ( undefined result not an url image ) but if i choose from media library then i press "insert to post" it was work.

here is my code :

```
    jQuery('.upload_image #upload_image_button').click(function() {


     formfield = jQuery('#upload_image').attr('name');
     tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
     targetInput = jQuery(this).next('input');
     previewImage = jQuery(this).prev('div');

    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
     imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');    
     targetInput.val(imgurl);
     previewImage.html('<img src="' + imgurl + '" width="100px" height="100px" />');
     tb_remove();
    }


 return false;
});
```

and here is my html :

```
<ul class="prev-thumb">
    <li  class="upload_image"> 
    <div class="preview-image"><?php echo(isset($images[0])) ? '<img src="'.$images[0].'" width="100px" height="100px" />' : ''; ?></div>
    <input class="button button-primary button-large"  id="upload_image_button" value="Upload Image" type="button" /> 
    <input id="upload_image" size="36" name="item[images][]" type="hidden" />  
    </li >


    <li  class="upload_image"> 
    <div class="preview-image"><?php echo(isset($images[1])) ? '<img src="'.$images[1].'" width="100px" height="100px" />' : ''; ?></div>
    <input class="button button-primary button-large"  id="upload_image_button" value="Upload Image" type="button" /> 
    <input id="upload_image" size="36" name="item[images][]" type="hidden" />  
    </li >


    <li  class="upload_image"> 
    <div class="preview-image"><?php echo(isset($images[2])) ? '<img src="'.$images[2].'" width="100px" height="100px" />' : ''; ?></div>
    <input class="button button-primary button-large"  id="upload_image_button" value="Upload Image" type="button" /> 
    <input id="upload_image" size="36" name="item[images][]" type="hidden" />  
    </li >


    <li  class="upload_image"> 
    <div class="preview-image"><?php echo(isset($images[3])) ? '<img src="'.$images[3].'" width="100px" height="100px" />' : ''; ?></div>
    <input class="button button-primary button-large"  id="upload_image_button" value="Upload Image" type="button" />
    <input id="upload_image" size="36" name="item[images][]" type="hidden" />  
    </li >
</ul>
```

sorry for my english and thanks in advance, i'm new here :)